# Correct way to restart presto-server service on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, presto

I have to restart `presto-server` on `EMR` to load my [`plugin`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/develop/spi-overview.html). With reference to official `AWS` `EMR` docs:

- [On some places](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-glue.html) they say

> `sudo restart presto-server`

- [On others](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-considerations.html) they say,

> `sudo stop presto-server` followed by `sudo start presto-server`

---

While [Restarting a service page](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restart-service-emr/) favours the 2nd technique above,

> **Note**: Stop/start is required; do not use the restart command.

I have found that both work without a glitch.

---

Questions:

- What's the difference between `sudo restart` & `sudo stop` + `sudo start`?
- Why the warning against `restart`?
- Which one to use for `presto-server`?

---

Platform / Frameworks:

- `emr-5.15.0`
- `Presto 0.212`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### EMR 6.1

```
sudo systemctl stop presto-server
sudo systemctl start presto-server
sudo systemctl status presto-server
```

#### EMR 5.15 (likely anything before 5.30)

`restart` does not reload the service configuration file (unfortunately, i don't remember the path to the file; this is the file which tells e.g. which user Presto runs as). Depending on the changes you introduce, this may or may not be an issue. Eg. if you are changing Presto config files or plugins, this is not an issue. If, however, you're changing the Presto service definition file, `restart` will not pick up your changes, whereas `stop` + `start` will.

**Note: while the answer hopefully is/was applicable to EMR 5.15, it seems not applicable to EMR 6.1.**

Answer (score 2):

The configs aren't picked up with the restarts. It's always suggested to use the start stops on EMR.

$sudo status presto-server
presto-server start/running, process 16147

$sudo stop presto-server
presto-server stop/waiting

$sudo stop presto-server
presto-server stop/waiting